# View SQL generated by ORMLite on Android

Tags: android, sql, ormlite

I'm trying to debug a weird problem with my ORMLite query in my Android app, and it would be really handy if I could see the SQL being generated. Is there any way to output the SQL of a query as a string? It doesn't matter if it's before or after the query is executed.

For example, I have

```
contactQb.where().eq("enabled", true);
```

I'd like to see what SQL is generated for that QueryBuilder.

Comment: Post some which could make sense to understand your problem even better.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out: `contactQb.prepareStatementString()` gives the full SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks @Gray, I had to wait out the timer to accept my own answer and then forgot about it!

Answer (score 10):

> Is there any way to output the SQL of a query as a string?

As you mention logging the output of `contactQb.prepareStatementString()` will show you the specific query string.  You can also enable ORMLite's logging to show a lot more detail.  See:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/android-logging